# How can I implement the recursion in my Quicksort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement quicksort in Java to learn basic algorithms. I understand how the algo works (and can do it on paper) but am finding it hard to write it in code. I've managed to do step where we put all elements smaller than the pivot to the left, and larger ones to the right (see my code below). However, I can't figure out how to implement the recursion part of the algo, so sort the left and right sides recursively. Any help please?

```
public void int(A, p, q){
    if(A.length == 0){ return; }
    int pivot = A[q];
    j = 0; k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(A[i] <= pivot){
            A[j] = A[i]; j++;
        }
        else{
            A[k] = A[i]; k++;
        }
    }
    A[j] = pivot;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive Quick Sort in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243597/recursive-quick-sort-in-java)

Comment: Are you sure `public void int(A, p, q)` is a valid signature?

Answer (score 0):

*Big Disclaimer*: I did not write this piece of code, so upvotes is not needed. But I link to a tutorial which explains quicksort in detail. Gave me a much needed refreshment on the algorithm as well! The example given has very good comments that might just help you to wrap your head around it.

I suggest you adapt it to your code and write som tests for it to verify it works

*Quicksort is a fast, recursive, non-stable sort algorithm which works by the divide and conquer principle. Quicksort will in the best case divide the array into almost two identical parts. It the array contains n elements then the first run will need O(n). Sorting the remaining two sub-arrays takes 2* O(n/2). This ends up in a performance of O(n log n).
In the worst case quicksort selects only one element in each iteration. So it is O(n) + O(n-1) + (On-2).. O(1) which is equal to O(n^2).*

```
public class Quicksort  {
private int[] numbers;
private int number;

public void sort(int[] values) {
    // check for empty or null array
    if (values ==null || values.length==0){
        return;
    }
    this.numbers = values;
    number = values.length;
    quicksort(0, number - 1);
}

private void quicksort(int low, int high) {
    int i = low, j = high;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    int pivot = numbers[low + (high-low)/2];

    // Divide into two lists
    while (i <= j) {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller than the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        // If the current value from the right list is larger than the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        // If we have found a value in the left list which is larger than
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller than the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        // As we are done we can increase i and j
        if (i <= j) {
            exchange(i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // This is the recursion part you had trouble with i guess?
    // Recursion
    if (low < j)
        quicksort(low, j);
    if (i < high)
        quicksort(i, high);
}

private void exchange(int i, int j) {
    int temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = temp;
}
}
```

[Link to tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html#quicksort)